# how to use redux-saga with async callback function

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, fingerprintjs2

I want to use redux-saga **yield call** effect with async function that get the result of this function is call back. ( in this case fingerprintjs but it's general case)

This is the async function I want to exactue :

```
new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components) {
console.log(result) // a hash, representing your device fingerprint
console.log(components) // an array of FP components
})
```

The issue that I want to execute this function via saga , but it's always stuck on yield call.

I try many ways :

```
import Fingerprint2 from 'fingerprintjs2';

const func = new Fingerprint2().get;
const res = yield call(func);
```

Also try like this:

```
import Fingerprint2 from 'fingerprintjs2';

const func = new Fingerprint2().get;
const a = yield call(func, (fingerprint, result) => ({
  fingerprint,
  result
}));
```

And like this:

```
import Fingerprint2 from 'fingerprintjs2';

let res = yield call(new Fingerprint2().get(), (fingerprint, result) => ({
  fingerprint,
  result
}));
```

Any one know about idea or some way to acheive my goal ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone want answer to the question , there is serval options:

with cps:

```
const { result, components } = yield cps(cb => new Fingerprint2().get((result, components) => cb(null, { result, components })))
```

with promise:

```
 function* rootSaga(){
// Wrapping you function into a promise
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  new Fingerprint2().get((result, components) => {
  resolve({ result, components })
})
})

 // Yield the promise And redux-saga will return the resolved value when the promise resolves
 const { result, components } = yield promise
// do some stuff about  result and components ...
}
```

credit: redux-saga github

Answer (score 1):

`yield` can accept Promise.

```
const {result, components} = yield new Promise(resolve => {
  new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components) {
    resolve({result, components})
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks , it's work but I have question : there is a way to achieve this without wrap it with promise ? I try with cps but it's also stack .